# Characters being replaced while calling java class

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I have a jsp file that contains this code,

```
<form id="testForm">
    <input type="hidden" value="study--study is negative--echocardiogram--" name="hidAllProc"/>
</form>
```

Now, I serialize this form using jQuery's .serialize() function and send it in a post request to another jsp, and then in this jsp I simply send the "request" object to a java class and use request.getParameters("hidAllProc") to retrieve the hidden field value.

Now, the problem is that I tried to print the value that I get in the java class and it was like this, "study..study is negative..echocardiogram..". All the "--" have been replaced by "..". I encountered this behavior only in a particular PC. This code runs perfectly in my and my friends PC. I need help since I tried alomost every possible thing that I can and have exhausted of all ideas!

Thanks,
Rishabh

Comment: What locale and language is the machine set to?  Also, what is your webserver?  Some webservers will refuse to process characters which fall outside their default character set unless they are explicitly configured.

Comment: @mcfinnigan: I had temporary access to the machine so don't have the info. We are using tomcat server.

Comment: @DimitarChristoff: sorry, I don't understand how do I check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery `serialize` serializes using utf8.
You might want to try put

```
<%@codepage=65001%>
```

at the top of the receiving page, it's the codepage for utf8.
If it doesn't work, on your java class, you can decode your your input with

```
URLDecoder.decode(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using UTF-8 encoding everywhere. If application runs on tomcat, here is the how-to:

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q8

Comment: Thanks for the link. Since the situation was urgent we used a workaround by using a different separator. Instead of "--" we used "xyzabcpqr" and it worked the way we wanted. Will surely look into the link though!